# UnixODBC: Problema formatação decimal

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, odbc

Montei um servidor com CentOS 7, SQL Server 2017, e UnixODBC

No tsql, os números ficam corretos.

Mas quando eu vejo no isql, os decimais estão separados por vírgula (,) ao invés de ponto (.).

Como eu posso corrigir este problema?

P.S.: O que eu quero mesmo é usar o número no PHP (está reclamando que o número está com problema de formatação)

**UPDATE:**
O erro que aparece no PHP é: 
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /usr/share/nginx/html/loja3/info_vend/achapeca.php on line 789

Vi agora que o erro ocorre quando uso o number_format do php

**UPDATE 2:**

Eu rodei o var_dump e Windows retornou:
string(12) "3.5000000000"
No CentOS:
 string(3) "3,5"

**UPDATE 3:**

Parece que a solução é retirar o number_format. Mas eu acho estranho porque precisa do number_format no Windows e no CentOS não. Algum veredito ou dica adicional?

Comment: consegue nos mostrar um exemplo ? onde os comandos estão sendo executados ?

Comment: Atenção que o SQL Server 2017 ainda não é a versão final. Por enquanto está disponível somente a CTP (Community Technology Preview). É para testes. Vide https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/05/17/sql-server-2017-ctp-2-1-now-available/

Comment: Sim, eu sei que a versão é um preview.
Mas como no sqlcmd e no tsql está ok, imagino que o problema seja alguma configuração que impacte o odbc mas não impacte o sqlcmd, nem o tsql
Um exemplo, no tsql, um número aparece como 22.40 e no isql aparece como 22,399999999999999

Comment: @ClaudioShigueoWatanabe: Como está declarada no banco de dados a coluna que exibe valor 22.40?

Comment: Um exemplo de campo assim é decimal(15,2). Pelo que vi, os campos que estão dando problema são todos decimal

Comment: Faça um `var_dump` só para vermos e por favor é **muito importante** que coloque a mensagem de erro completa que ocorre no PHP aqui para vermos. Só para constar, você vê a virgula no isql, mas não significa que seja virgula de verdade é apenas uma maneira do isql facilitar a leitura, no banco esta normal.

Comment: O erro que aparece no PHP é:
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /usr/share/nginx/html/loja3/info_vend/achapeca.php on line 789

Comment: Vi agora que o erro ocorre quando uso o number_format do php

Answer (score 3):

Está parecendo uma questão de definição de idioma (*language*) na apresentação. Por exemplo, no idioma inglês o separador de casa decimal é o ponto e em português é a vírgula. Avalie o comportamento do isql com o uso da opção  `-l` (locale), definindo o idioma inglês.

No ODBC.ini, verifique como está configurado LOCALE. Verifique também a configuração de LC_NUMERIC no Cent OS.

A respeito do valor 22.*40* aparecer como 23.*99999*..., isso ocorre geralmente com expressões de [ponto flutuante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante); por exemplo, quando a coluna está declarada como `float` no banco de dados. Dependendo da forma como o valor é arredondado para ser exibido, pode ocorrer essa diferença, conforme descrito no documento [Using decimal, float, and real Data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912.aspx): *The IEEE 754 specification provides four rounding modes: round to nearest, round up, round down, and round to zero. Microsoft SQL Server uses round up. All are accurate to the guaranteed precision but can result in slightly different floating-point values. Because the binary representation of a floating-point number may use one of many legal rounding schemes, it is impossible to reliably quantify a floating-point value*.

---

**AMPLIAÇÃO**:
**(1)** No isql é possível definir locale, utilizando a opção `-l`. Detalhes em [isql man page](https://www.mankier.com/1/isql).

**(2)** Para obter informações sobre o driver ODBC da Microsoft para CentOS (clone do RHEL): [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server)

**(3)** Instruções de instalação do unixODBC, para atuar como driver manager em conjunto com o MS ODBC Driver: [Installing the Driver Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-driver-manager)

**(4)** Documentação de definição de locale no PHP: [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php)

Comment: Obrigado, José!
No /etc/odbc.ini tentei:
Locale = en_US
Mas não adiantou
Mas digitando no shell:
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Aí funcionou. Alguma ideia como poderia fazer funcionar no php?
Eu estou com medo de dar problema em outra coisa mudando o locales. Será que tem outro jeito?

Comment: No php, com setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US') funcionou. A pergunta que fica é: será que tem algum jeito melhor?

Comment: @ClaudioShigueoWatanabe: No PHP funcionou mantendo configurações originais do ODBC.ini e do CentOS? // Ao configurar o locale no PHP, o valor passou a ser exibido corretamente? Isto é, ficou 22.40? // Não posso opinar sobre PHP, pois não é _minha praia_, mas é onde ocorre a apresentação. // Se possível altere somente LC_NUMERIC.

Comment: Digitando no shell: export LANG=en_US.UTF-8, e testando o isql o valor fica 22.399999999999999

Comment: LC_NUMERIC também funciona. Obrigado!

Comment: @ClaudioShigueoWatanabe: A vantagem de utilizar LC_NUMERIC é que altera somente a parte de separador de milhar e de casa decimal. Existe também o LC_MONETARY, para moeda. //  Se conseguir tratar somente na apresentação (isql, PHP ou o que utilizar ao final), melhor.  // Ampliei a resposta, com links para documentação.

Comment: Obrigado, José! E desculpe... Meu último update estava errado e faltou falar no comentário aqui. No Windows está funcionando com number_format (função do php para formatação numérica) mas no CentOS funciona tirando o number_format. Sei que php não é sua praia mas você tem alguma opinião do que pode ser o problema?

Comment: @ClaudioShigueoWatanabe: Sobre "_No Windows está funcionando com number_format (função do php para formatação numérica) mas no CentOS funciona tirando o number_format_", assim como no CentOS a opção LC_NUMERIC define o tratamento para separador de milhar e de casa decimal, no Windows há opção semelhante em "Configurações Regionais". Verifique se ambas (no CentOS e no Windows) estão configuradas da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ClaudioShigueoWatanabe
```

Acredito que é o mesmo problema que tinha um sistema que desenvolvi, utilizando um drive de ODBC para SQL Server. Em algum ponto do programa do ODBC ele não realiza o arredondamento do valor, não encontrei uma explicação aceitável para tal fato, mas observei que tinha uma relação com o formato do dado no banco de dados.
Sempre que utilizava os programas para consultar a base diretamente o valor estava correto, quando utilizava o sistema com o drive ODBC tinha o problema, bom tinha que solucionar, então criai arredondamentos para os casos.
Outra solução foi em todos os campos que continham valores decimais, foram colocado máscaras para exibir.
Para engrossar o caldo, quando realizava o insert através da aplicação, o valor persistia na base corretamente, porém na recuperação da mesma tela aparecia com casas decimais que não tinham.
Espero que encontre uma solução, comigo somente alterando para ADO, porém não continuei no projeto para saber se isto foi de fato solucionado.
Desenvolvi no Delphi 5 e 7 para MS SqlServer 7 a 2012, o drive de ODBC apenas o conhecia MSSQLOdbc.

Comment: Nossa Luiz... Espero que seu problema não tenha nada a ver com o seu... O seu parece ser pior que o meu.

Comment: O mais interessante que não eram todos os valores, eram em valores aleatórios.
<br/> Todos os cálculos eram realizados corretamente, apenas o visual do campo ficou prejudicado no sistema, solucionava com máscaras e trocando o tipo de componente para exibir o valor.